# Как перегрузить операторы >> и << для разного типа файлов

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

У меня есть структура на подобии такой :

```
struct Product 
{
    int code;
    char name[10];
    int price;
};
```

Я хочу, чтобы она могла записываться в файлы как бинарного формата, так и файлы обычного формата.

Перегрузил операции для бинарного формата :

```
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& out, const Product& product) {
    out.write((char*)&product.code, sizeof(product.code));
    out.write((char*)&product.name, sizeof(product.name));
    out.write((char*)&product.price, sizeof(product.price));
    return out;
}

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& in, Product& product) { 
    in.read((char*)&product.code, sizeof(product.code));
    in.read((char*)&product.name, sizeof(product.name));
    in.read((char*)&product.price, sizeof(product.price));
    return in;
}
```

Однако как их перезагрузить и для обычного формата? Ибо синтаксис в бинарном файле и синтаксис в обычном файле различаются, из-за чего у меня на выходе выходит непойми что.

Comment: Может по потоку и можно узнать, бинарный он или нет, но так обычно не делают. Заметили, что стандартные перегрузки `<<` всегда пишут в текстовом виде?

Comment: А как обычно делают? Просто несколько функций, без перегрузок операторов?

Comment: Потоки просто файлы/объекты можно конечно смотреть флаги потока. Единственный "нормальный" путь который приходит в голову, это создать наследников от вашей структуры которые по разному будут перегружать операторы вывода, и при выводе в поток приводить вашу структуру к нужному типу.

Comment: @Yakov *"при выводе в поток приводить вашу структуру к нужному типу"* Пахнет UB из-за нарушения strict aliasing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну этого можно избежать копированием объекта в конструкторе, по аналогии с std::string, я же указал "нормальный" в том плане, что это не совсем правильное/надежное решение, так же как и попытка опереться на флаги потока.

Comment: @Yakov А тогда пахнет лишним копированием. :) Уж лучше сделать структуру с единственным полем - ссылкой на сериализуемый класс, и для нее перегрузить `<<`. И будет что-то в стиле [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted).

Comment: *"Просто несколько функций, без перегрузок операторов?"* Как больше нравится. Можно так, можно сделать `<<` для текстового вывода и функцию для двоичного.

Comment: ну люди ленивые )) иначе бы досихпор на ассемблере писали, компромиссный вариант добавить формат в саму структуру, в операторе смотреть на это значение и выбирать как выводить данные.

Comment: кстати насчет уб это спорный момент. типы то полностью совместимы, члены расположен по одним адресам. их типы одинаковы. можно приводить один к другому безопасно, у них только таблицы виртуальных функций будут разные, но они же содержатся не в самом объекте структуры.

Comment: Стандарт C11 говорит следующее в разделе “6.5 Выражения” параграфа 7:

Объект должен иметь свое сохраненное значение, доступ к которому осуществляется только с помощью выражения lvalue, имеющего один из следующих типов: 88) — тип, совместимый с эффективным типом объекта,— квалифицированная версия типа, совместимого с действующим типом объекта,
— тип, который является типом со знаком или без знака, соответствующим квалифицированному типу объекта. к сожалению что там поменялось в текущем стандарте не помню, да свежего компилятора под рукой нет. VS 2017 скушала и не подавилась. без ворнингов.

Comment: вот вам код https://pastebin.com/xAm0BE55 в этом примере ( только с выводом в поток ) сложно будет выстрелить себе в ногу. хотя как это гцц переварит - не знаю.

Comment: Пишите точно так же, только выводите каждое поле в отдельной строке, а потом читайте *строки*... Если `name` - гарантированно одно слово, можно все писать в одну строку. Ну, а как иметь 2 перегрузки одного и того же оператора? Да никак - просто для текста использовать потоковые операторы, для бинарника - read/write (вы же ими пользуетесь, они вам не смущают? :))

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/be5GGG

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос, на который, как мне кажется, нет хорошего ответа в рамках потоков С++

Есть следующие механизмы, которые вроде как призваны управлять форматом вывода, но они не помогут:

- i/o манипуляторы вроде `std::boolalpha`. Меняют состояние потока, устанавливая соотвествующий `std::ios_base::fmtflags`. Свой флаг добавить к стандартным нельзя
- режим открытия файла `binary`. тут проблема с эффективностью и валидностью приведения произвольного `ostream` к `ofstream` (в общем случае оператор << следует писать для `ostream` вообще, а не для `ofstream`), плюс `binary` режим не для этого, и подобное нарушает принцип наименьшего удивления

Как воркэраунд, выглядящий не очень большим злом, я бы предложил сделать отдельные типы со ссылочной сематникой, сериализующие Product. Например шаблонные `SerializeAsText<T>` и `SerializeAsBinary<T>` со специализациями `SerializeAsText<Product>` `SerializeAsBinary<Product>`. Ну или не шаблонные.

Как совсем костыли, скрытое состояние потока в мапе, в глобальной переменной или thread local storage переменной.

В библиотеках сериализации, вроде boost serialization, бинарность сериализации данных является свойством потока, клиентский код просто делает `out << product.code`  (или даже `s & product.code` при совмещенной реализации сериализации и десериализации)